# Scrollbar and search bar in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

```
listacsv = os.path.abspath("spiders//")

game = tk.Tk()
game.geometry("1000x650")
game.title('test')
game.resizable(0,0)

entry = tk.Entry(game)
entry.pack(side="left", ipady=5, ipadx=65, anchor='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

frame1 = tk.Frame(game)
frame1.pack(side='right', padx=5)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1,width=500,height=700,scrollregion=(100,120,5000,5000))
vbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame1,orient='vertical')
vbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=500,height=700)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side='right',expand=True,fill='both')

tk.Button(game, text='Options',activebackground='#87a0c7',relief='solid', command='', height = 2, width = 10).place(x=5, y=600) 

with open(listacsv + '/list.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(f)
    data = list(reader)

c = 4
r = math.ceil(len(data)/c)
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    onclick = lambda url=item[0]: webbrowser.open(url)
    tk.Button(canvas, text=item[1], command=onclick, activebackground='#87a0c7',relief='sunken', height = 3, width = 19, padx=10).grid(column=i//r, row=i%r)      


verlabel=tk.Label(game, text='Version: '+ currentver, relief='flat')
verlabel.place(x=125, y=619)
game.mainloop()
```

I see the scrollbar but it has no effect on the frame, the buttons don't move.

Any idea on how to show only the buttons that have in the text the words written in the search bar?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create another frame and put it into `canvas` using `canvas.create_window(...)`.  Then make all the buttons the children of this frame instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i managed how to do it having taken into account the answers, i post the code in case someone encountered the same problem.

```
frame1 = tk.Frame(game)
frame1.pack(side='right', padx=0)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1,width=660,height=700)
canvas.pack(side='right',expand=True)
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame1, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y') 
my_scrollbar.place(x=645,relheight='1')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all")))
second_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor='ne')
```

And then used second_frame for the widgets.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you placed your button in your game window, and your scrollbar in frame1. **Make sure the button and the scrollbar are placed in the same thing**. If you want anything else to be on frame1 change it. After they are the same your code will look like this:

```
listacsv = os.path.abspath("spiders//")

game = tk.Tk()
game.geometry("1000x650")
game.title('test')
game.resizable(0,0)

entry = tk.Entry(game)
entry.pack(side="left", ipady=5, ipadx=65, anchor='nw', padx=10, pady=10)

frame1 = tk.Frame(game)
frame1.pack(side='right', padx=5)
canvas = tk.Canvas(frame1,width=500,height=700,scrollregion=(100,120,5000,5000))
vbar=tk.Scrollbar(frame1,orient='vertical')
vbar.pack(side='right',fill='y')
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
canvas.config(width=500,height=700)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side='right',expand=True,fill='both')

tk.Button(frame1, text='Options',activebackground='#87a0c7',relief='solid', command='', height = 2, width = 10).place(x=5, y=600) 

with open(listacsv + '/list.csv', newline='', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(f)
    data = list(reader)

c = 4
r = math.ceil(len(data)/c)
for i, item in enumerate(data):
    onclick = lambda url=item[0]: webbrowser.open(url)
    tk.Button(canvas, text=item[1], command=onclick, activebackground='#87a0c7',relief='sunken', height = 3, width = 19, padx=10).grid(column=i//r, row=i%r)      


verlabel=tk.Label(frame1, text='Version: '+ currentver, relief='flat')
verlabel.place(x=125, y=619)
game.mainloop()
```

Comment: The label and the button options must be outside of the frame, the buttons that i want to scroll are                                                                                                                     
 tk.Button(canvas,text=item[1],command=onclick,activebackground='#87a0c7',relief='sunken', height = 3, width = 19, padx=10).grid(column=i//r, row=i%r)'

Comment: Then put your scrollbar on the game screen also. Don't put the scrollbar in a frame then.

Comment: But i have all the buttons in a frame why i have to put the scrollbar in game?

Comment: If you want the scrollbar to work, that's what I would do...